# Can I select three IDs with a shorter jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

I believe there is some better way for selecting these three IDs from a dropdown-list (ID 115, 116 and 117):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var usedNames = {};
    $("select[name='item_meta[115]'] > option").each(function () {
        if(usedNames[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });

    var usedNames = {};
    $("select[name='item_meta[116]'] > option").each(function () {
        if(usedNames[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });

    var usedNames = {};
    $("select[name='item_meta[117]'] > option").each(function () {
        if(usedNames[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Can I make this code shorter, and have all the IDs selected under the first variable?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Read the selectors API.

Comment: Also read what [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) does. You're declaring the same variable thrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("select[name^='item_meta'] > option")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='item_meta[116]'] > option")
    .add("select[name='item_meta[117]'] > option")
    .add("select[name='item_meta[118]'] > option")
    ...
```

Or

```
var selector = "select[name='item_meta[116]'] > option"
selector += ",select[name='item_meta[117]'] > option"
selector += ",select[name='item_meta[118]'] > option";

$(selector)
    ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an asterisk * to select all of them?

Comment: No.  `*` is an element name wild card, and has nothing to do with attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var usedNames = {},
    pattern = 'select[name="item_meta[<ID>]"] > option', // Create a string pattern for the selector
    IDs = [115, 116, 117, 121], // Get your arbitrary list of ID's
    selectors = IDs.map(pattern, function (ID) { return pattern.replace('<ID>', ID) }), // return an array of string selectors
    elems = $(selectors.join(',')); // query for all of them

$.each( elems, function () {

    if(usedNames[this.text]) {

        $(this).remove();

    } else {

        usedNames[this.text] = this.value;

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to make sense, however I can't get it to work. I have a page with three dropdowns, and what I'm aiming for is to prevent choices from repeating.

Live site: http://fluefiske.net/fluemonstre/

Comment: Not sure what I should be looking at on the site. Try opening the web inspector in Chrome throwing a `debugger` statement in the line under $.each and running through to see what happens. As long as you're not redefining var usedNames = {} all over again as you have in your example, it should work. When you do that, you're deleting it and recreating it blank.